# Is it bad practice to use reactive variables without declaring them in the reactive interface first?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuejs3, vue-reactivity, vue-script-setup

I see 2 approaches in using the `reactive` interface.

**First**: Declaring all variables before assignment:

```
const state = reactive({
    name: '',
    age: 0,
    gender: ''
})
```

and assign them later:

```
state.name = 'mike'
state.age = 35
state.gender = 'male'
```

**Second**: Just create the `reactive` object:

```
const state = reactive({})
```

and create variables during assingment:

```
state.name = 'mike'
state.age = 35
state.gender = 'male'
```

The first approach is more work but gives you said `interface`, which serves as an overview of all reactive objects. Recently I find myself often just skipping it and just create variables "on the go".

Is it bad practice to use reactive variables without declaring them in the reactive interface first?

Comment: My gut feeling says that without explicit typing you might run into issues with typescript if you want to use that later on. I've not used Vue 3 enough to make a definitive list of potential problems though.

Comment: I would suggest replacing the last sentence with the question in your title. The title seems like an answerable question. The last sentence feels more opinion based.

Comment: Both are acceptable. The first one makes more sense because it's more maintainable, also  will get better types in IDE